# How do I search mongodb based off dates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Building a rental listing application using MERN stack. My Listing model is below:

```
const listingShcema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    hostedBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    numberOfGuests: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    numberOfRooms: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    numberOfBeds: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    numberOfBaths: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: String,
      requried: true,
    },
    location: {
      streetAddress: { type: String },
      city: { type: String },
      state: { type: String },
      postalCode: { type: String },
    },
    bookedDates: [
      {
        startDate: Date,
        endDate: Date,
      },
    ],
    imgUrls: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
    amenities: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Now it is fairly easy to run queries on everything given by the users search query except for the dates they want to rent out. The listing model keeps track of all bookedDates. I want to be able search the mongodb for Listings that do not have bookedDates that match the dates supplied by the users search query (showing available listings to the user). I can't think of a way to do this?? I figured it is easy keeping track of only the booked dates instead of taking away booked dates from an array of all available dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this directly in the DB is kind of awkward, especially if you're only storing the `startDate` and `endDate` for each booking. For example, if someone books a listing from the 1st to the 5th - if another user is searching for the same listing from the 3rd to the 7th, it doesn't match the booking saved, but the listing wouldn't still be counted as available.

I'd suggest taking another look at your model and perhaps even separating out the booked dates to their own documents.

But, keeping with what you have, assuming you're not booking too far in the future, it might be worth storing the `bookedDates` as a flat array. So if we have a listing booked from the 1st to the 3rd, and the 6th to the 8th, your array would look like this:

```
bookedDates: [
    '2021-01-01',
    '2021-01-02',
    '2021-01-03',
    '2021-01-06',
    '2021-01-07',
    '2021-01-08'
]
```

Then, if someone searches for the listing between the 2nd and 4th, you'd again break down those dates into a flat array, and then you should be able to use the `$nin` operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

```
const desiredDates = [
    '2021-01-02',
    '2021-01-03',
    '2021-01-04'
]
Listing.find({ bookedDates: { $nin: desiredDates } })
```

To quote the relevant part of the page:

> If the field holds an array, then the $nin operator selects the documents whose field holds an array with no element equal to a value in the specified array (e.g. , , etc.).

This is obviously going to work best if you have another way to filter out the majority of your listings, so your not doing an array-array check for every listing in your database.

You'll also have to keep `bookedDates` up-to-date by removing past dates.

Another option is just to query your listings and do the date filtering at the application level, in which case, you can probably keep the `startDate` and `endDate` format that you have.

**Update for flattening dates**

Something like this should work. I just brute force it - people are generally only going to book a listing for a few days mostly, so your loop is going to be quite small. There are some checks in there if it's for one day, and to make sure the start is before the end, but that's about it.

As a method, you can call it whenever you want, and it'll split two dates into a flattened string array in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

```
function getFlattenedDatesAr(inputStart, inputEnd) {
    // convert to dates and make sure that start is before end
    let startDate = new Date(inputStart)
    let endDate = new Date(inputEnd)
    if(startDate > endDate) {
        let temp = startDate;
        startDate = endDate;
        endDate = temp;
    }

    // get our dates in yyyy-mm-dd format
    const startDateStr = startDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    const endDateStr = endDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)

    // check if they've only booked for one day
    if(startDateStr === endDateStr) {
        return [startDateStr];
        return; 
    }
    
    // fill our our dates array
    const bookedDates = [startDateStr]
    let currDate = startDate;
    while(true) {
        // NOTE: setDate returns a timestamp, not a Date
        const nextDateTS = currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);
        
        // get our date string and add it to our bookedDates array
        currDate = new Date(nextDateTS)
        const currDateStr = currDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
        bookedDates.push(currDateStr);
        
        // if our string matches our end date, we're done
        if(currDateStr === endDateStr) {
            break
        }
    }
    return bookedDates
}


// assume these are the dates sent, in yyyy-mm-dd format
let inputStart = '2021-01-01'
let inputEnd = '2021-01-05'

const datesAr = getFlattenedDatesAr(inputStart, inputEnd)
console.log(datesAr);
```

Comment: How would you suggest I go about getting the other dates in between, the two given desired start and end dates, to add to the array of bookedDates?

Comment: @stinny I've added an edit to show how I'd do it